# Angular chart.js hide dots on 1 dataset

Tags: angular-chart

Chart.js is amazing, but I'm using angularjs chart.js directive. I can turn off all dots on all lines with the below code where vm.options is set to the chart-options attribute:

```
vm.options = {
            elements: {
                point: {
                    radius: 0
                }
            }
        };
```

However, I'd only like to hide the dots on 2 of the 3 datasets I have and I'm not sure how to get that for angularjs chart.js. My dataset's is just an array of arrays of data (not an object), and when I look at chart.js and how they hide dots they do it on a dataset object, but that doesn't match how I'm doing my datasets so I'm confused.

Comment: Hi! Could you provide a plunker with your code?

Comment: You need to give some example code and tell people which specific lib you're using with a link. There are multiple chartjs wrapper directive libs out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `pointRadius: 0` in your `$scope.datasetOverride` to turn off dots for each dataset

```
$scope.datasetOverride = [{    
    label: "No Dots Line",
    fill: true,
    pointRadius: 0,
  }];
```

https://codepen.io/vfx/pen/dLpEgW

Comment: You nailed it man! Thank you so much. Being new to chart.js its confusing for me to describe what I want as shown by some of the comments on my post but you nailed it!